# Function to identify lines and writing in one file (csv)

Tags: python, file, csv, lines, identify

I have a log file with a lot of lines. The log file is in csv Format. I am searching in that file for different Messages and I want to store them in a different file.

How can I manage that?

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
with open('/tmp/result/warnings/test/test3.csv', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('/tmp/result/warnings/test/test4.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if not "Failed to open output file" in line:
                output_file.write(line)

with open('/tmp/result/warnings/test/test4.csv', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('/tmp/result/warnings/test/test5.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if not "Invalid file length of" in line:
                output_file.write(line)
```

Can I do it like looking up several Messages in once and then write in in one file?

Comment: Are you trying to find messages that match all conditions, or send messages with different contents to different files?

Comment: I am trying to find messages matching all conditions and write those to one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('/tmp/result/warnings/test/test3.csv', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('/tmp/result/warnings/test/test4.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        conditions = [not "Failed to open output file" in line, not "Invalid file length of" in line]
        if all(conditions):
            output_file.write(line)
```

Will allow you to check against multiple conditions and if they are [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) true, write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super-modularized version:

```
# assumes Python 2.7
import csv

def read_csv(fname, header=False, **kwargs):
    with open(fname, "rb") as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf, **kwargs)
        if header:
            head = next(incsv, [])
        for row in incsv:
            yield row

def write_csv(fname, rows, **kwargs):
    with open(fname, "wb") as outf:
        outcsv = csv.writer(outf, **kwargs)
        outcsv.writerows(rows)

def multi_filter(items, any_of=None, all_of=None):
    if any_of is None and all_of is None:
        return items

    if any_of is None:
        test_any = lambda item: True
    else:
        test_any = lambda item: any(cond(item) for cond in any_of)

    if all_of is None:
        test_all = lambda item: True
    else:
        test_all = lambda item: all(cond(item) for cond in all_of)

    return (item for item in items if test_any(item) and test_all(item))

def csv_filter(inf, outf, any_of=None, all_of=None):
    write_csv(outf, multi_filter(read_csv(inf), any_of, all_of))

conditions = [
    lambda row: not row[2].startswith("Failed to open output file"),
    lambda row: not row[2].startswith("Invalid file length of")
]

inf = '/tmp/result/warnings/test/test3.csv'
outf = '/tmp/result/warnings/test/test5.csv'
csv_filter(inf, outf, all_of(conditions))
```

Comment: Hey, yes it's Python 2.7 (sorry I forgot). I will test ypour code today. Thanks so far!

Comment: Your solution worked, but I took the one from C.B. because it fits better my program and what I want to do. It leads to less lines. - Thank you!